why ngClass stop working with dynamic data
I have a weird situation. I try to use [ngClass] and it add the class just when my data is mocked in the service, when I call the endpoint, the [ngClass] stop working. Why does it have this behavior?
Here is my code:
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
   <a [ngClass]="{ 'active': (firstObservable$ | async) && 
       ((secondObservable$ | async) === item)}">
   </a>
</ng-container>

Same behavior for [class.className]="condition".
I also tried to import NgClass in my .ts file, as long as I work with standalone components, but didn't help.

You have a === in (secondObservable$ | async) === item which checks for the type as well as value so are you sure that the data returned by the API satisfies this comparison. Also it will be helpful if you can add some more details like the data returned from the API as without that it's difficult to find the problem.

Yes, it satisfies the comparison. It works perfectly when I use data mocked in the frontend service, it only crash when I call the endpoint. I checked the data from the backend, is the same as my mock. The data returned is an array with objects. Each object has name, code and subscribed fields. I don't understand why ngClass stop working with data from backend.

Since you have a lot of validations that have to do with the data present inside, it's a better idea to opt out of async pipe. When you have complex logic that depends on the underlying observable, subscribing and assigning the value to a variable is a better idea.
items: Array<any> = [];
firstItem: any = null;

this.someService.getData().subscribe((response) => {
    this.items = response;
    this.firstItem = response.find((item: any) => item.subscribed);
    ...
});

Then the HTML can be simplified to:
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
   <!-- {{firstItem === item}} -->
   <a [ngClass]="{ 'active': firstItem === item }"></a>
</ng-container>

Try this approach of subscribing and setting data, also to check why ngClass did not work all you need to do is add {{firstItem === item}} in HTML like shown above in comments, which will help you debug why ngClass is false.
